# Remove items from one list if they contain strings from another list

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, linq

I'm looking for the most efficient way to remove items from one list if they contain strings from another list.

For example:

B list contains:

```
TomWentFishing
SueStayedHome
JohnGoesToSchool
JimPlaysTennis
```

A list contains:

```
GoesToSchool
SueStayed
```

C list should contain:

```
TomWentFishing
JimPlaysTennis
```

I've used this code, but it takes up a lot of time as the lists are very large:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] b = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\b.txt");
        string[] a = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\a.txt");

        foreach (string firststring in b)
        {
            bool contains = false;
            foreach (string secondstring in a)
            {
                if (firststring.ToLower().Contains(secondstring.ToLower()))
                {
                    contains = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (contains == false)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(@"C:\c.txt", firststring + Environment.NewLine);
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: If you're looking for better performance on **large** arrays use `Array.Sort(...)` on both arrays and then use `Array.BinarySearch(...)` to test if the array contains the item

Comment: Read file B into a set at the start. This way you dont have to keep rereading it and it has fast lookup

Comment: @Lukas will the substrings always be bounded on words? Or will file A perhaps have `eGoesToSchoo` ? Alternatively, will the words in A always either start or end a word in B?

Comment: Theer are algorithms to more efficiently find one and the same string in a set of strings, e.g. [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) which pre-processes the search string in order to skip parts that could never match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this **significantly** faster if you can sort the `a` list into something that can support binary (or faster) lookups.

Unfortunately, the `Contains()` search makes this challenging. But there are still some things we can do:

- Avoid loading all of `b` into RAM. Ever.
- On the other hand, lookups into `a` will be faster if we preload into RAM **once**, and do as much work to support the lookups for this one copy as we can.
- Only convert `b` to lower case once, instead of again for each line in `a`.
- It will be more efficient to do all of the write operations at once, rather than re-opening the output file to append the lines as we find them.
- As a bonus, we'll do all this in significantly less code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var b = File.ReadLines(@"C:\b.txt");
    var a = File.ReadLines(@"C:\a.txt").Select(line => line.ToLower()).ToList();

    var result = b.Where(bline => {
       var lowered = bline.ToLower();
       return !a.Any(aline => lowered.Contains(aline));
    });

    File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\c.txt", result);
}
```

Comment: @AskarRayapov Correct. This is still fundamentally the same algorithm, with only a few savings here and there (reduced ram use for B, reduced extra ToLower() calls in A, reduced file seeks for C).

Comment: @Askar *does not do the single loop* - it still requires two loops; one on the where and one on the any

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn saw the edit about the loop, deleted the comment hence.
Do you think under the hood it would save more if contains is used with the string comparison overload, and then the select also would not require the tolower ?

e.g. firststring.Contains(secondstring, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

Comment: @AskarRayapov possibly, but it's one of those things I'd want to profile for. Certainly `OrdinalIgnoreCase` is more **correct** generally, which is even more important than the performance difference. But I suspect this data set can be show to be _safe_ for the naiive `ToLower()`, and that pre-caching the lower-case version of the `a` values to use exact matches will be faster.

Comment: @CaiusJard yeap, that was what I initially was hinting to :)

Comment: Thank you. This works significantly faster.

Comment: Doesn't this also run `bLine.ToLower()` potentially as many times as there are items in `a`? Put the `bline.ToLower()` in a `Select` on the `ReadLines` and don't `ToList` it (or put a select between the b and the where). Or skip ToLower and use a StringComparison.XXIgnoreCase

Comment: @CaiusJard It does. I'm working on fixing that in a way that still preserves the original case for the output. It's taking longer because I wanted to show off a little and still keep a single-line lambda, but I may not succeed there (I could .Select() into a Tuple, but that seems like overkill).

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a very efficient implementation based on hash set, it is linear time complexity O(n). This avoids you to iterate over all lines of a.txt file for each line in b.txt file which leads to quadratic time complexity O(n^2).

This approach is good if a hash set with all the lines of a.txt files fits in memory. It it doesn't fit in memory then you need to use something like RocksDb.

First you have this extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableStringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> Minus(
        this IEnumerable<string> minuend, 
        IEnumerable<string> subtrahend, 
        StringComparison comparisonType)
    {
        var subtrahendSet = new HashSet<string>(subtrahend, StringComparer.FromComparison(comparisonType));
        return minuend.Where(x => subtrahendSet.Contains(x) == false);
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateLines(string filePath)
    {
        using (var reader = File.OpenText(filePath))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                yield return line;
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var minuend = EnumerateLines("b.txt");
        var sustraend = EnumerateLines("a.txt");
        var difference = minuend.Minus(sustraend, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        File.WriteAllLines("difference.txt", difference);

    }
}
```

Note that with this implementation you don't need to keep all lines from b.txt file in memory at once. But you need a hash set with all lines from a.txt

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is high memory usage because of large file size, then one file you have read anyway but for other one instead of reading the entire file in memory directly, you can use FileInputStream with BufferedReader to read lines one by one. This will reduce some memory usage

Comment: *to read lines one by one from both files and do rest of the logic* - interested to see how you achieve a nested loops contains check like this, while leaving most the file on disk, without beating the living daylights out of the disk..